# Django datetime field fractional support

Tags: django, django-models, mariadb

I have Django 1.9.5 installed with MariaDB 10.1.13 (also tested with MySQL 5.6.30) (which was updated from MySQL 5.5) and I am trying to get fractional seconds support in a date time field.

I have created a test model to try and get this working, here is the definition

```
class History(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

then in the shell I have run the following

```
History(date=datetime.now()).save()
```

and then when I query it

```
type(History.objects.get(id=1).date)
```

I get

```
<type 'NoneType'>
```

even though the entry appears in the database.

I can also use the field in a query

```
History.objects.all().order_by('date')
```

I know it works because inspecting the data shows that the order has changed

But I need to be able to return the date so I can compare it with another.

I was using the MySQL 5.5 without fractional support but there are records in my database that have the same datetime field and thus the order_by didnt work, I was using order_by id and that worked whilst the records were entered chronologically, but now this isnt the case I need fractional support.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you are querying the same object you just created? It seems unlikely if there are other objects in the database (of which the first would have `id=1`, not the one you just created).

Comment: Yes Im sure, this is just a test table and there is no data in it

Comment: Once you save `History(date=datetime.now()).save()` could you check what is its `id`?

Comment: it was 1, and I used .get(id=1) to query it

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of situation it might be better to store the date and time as a unix timestamp in the database. There you millisecond accuracy. You can convert to python datetime objects at anytime with [fromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp).

Last but not least, you can easily convert unix timestamps with javascript to date times in the user's own timezone. A process that's far more complex with django or any other server side tech.

Comment: For the majority of cases I am using the auto_now and auto_now_add options, so I am not actually entering the data (I created the above scenario to test). These do work but the data that gets stored is not fractional either. Also I am sure there are workarounds to this but it should work and I want to know why it isnt. If I find that it is just not possible currently then I will resort to a work around